# If you love fruit then you may know my enemy

Tags: riddle

I am owned by one but used by many
I can do some things much faster than any human being
But you may also look through me and see
A special world of beauty

HINT:

> When I was young, you would find me in rolling green hills of bliss

What am I?

Comment: Nice riddle but the title made things too obvious for me :D

Comment: @KevinL That's what I was thinking as well, thanks for the input!

Comment: It was solved within minutes of being posted

Comment: Lol, when El-Guest is online, there's no puzzle left unanswered XD

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you

> Windows? (Or Microsoft?)

I am owned by one but used by many

> Owned by Microsoft (Bill Gates) but used by many computers

I can do some things much faster than any human being

> Windows can run things faster than any human

But you may also look through me and see A special world of beauty

> This is a Window

Hint:

> Windows XP’s desktop default background was a rolling green field.

Title:

> Windows’ enemy is MacIntosh (ie. Apple) a type of fruit.

Comment: Nice! I like your answer to the last hint much better. +1

Comment: that's got to be it!

Comment: Yep, that's it!

Comment: The hint goes deeper: rot13(gur gvgyr bs KC'f qrfxgbc vzntr vf "Oyvff" uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Oyvff_(vzntr))

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you're

> Netflix

I am owned by one but used by many

> Nobody actually owns a netflix account, they use someone elses

I can do some things much faster than any human being

> Netflix can transmit shows and movies far faster than going to blockbuster or dealing with shipping

But you may also look through me and see

> you watch shows through netflix (a bit of a stretch)

A special world of beauty

> Planet Earth is spectacular if you haven't seen it

A little tongue in cheek, but I say it still works :)

Bonus:

> "If you love fruit then you may know my enemy", netflix routinely competes against Apple for recruits and prestige (FAANG)

Comment: Nice answer, but not what I was looking for. You are very close though! You got the bonus correct, I will add a hint for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

> Android

I am owned by one but used by many

> Owned by Google, but loaded on android devices for people's use.

I can do some things much faster than any human being

> As generally most software can in some fashion.

But you may also look through me and see
A special world of beauty

> So, unsure here. To me: looking through the code can be pretty neat. Generally, it could just be the use of the OS.

Title:

> Thanks @JGibbers. Android competes with Apple.

Comment: last clue may refer to (rot13) n pnzren